# Mysql/php - Is it possible update a table with a loop but without a key?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, indexing

Is it possible to make a procedure that update rows in a mysql table without a primary key?

I have a table like this, that correspond to teachers's schedules:

```
TEACHER_ID | WEEK_DAY |  HOUR | CLASS

1234567         2        11:30  MAT001
1234567         2        13:00  HIS001
```

I want to load a .csv file with their schedules and that the procedure finds if the rows on it already exist on the table, update them or, in the case that don't exist, insert them.

My table doesn't have a primary, because the system where we got the .csv files doesn't create one.

What I thought was combine the fields "TEACHER _ID","WEEK_DAY" and "HOUR" as a key when use "WHERE" for the update/insert on the table, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Can achieve what I want? Can you help me?

Thank you in advance for your answers!

(I apologize in advance for the mistakes on my grammar errors)

Comment: It's hard to help you without knowing exactly what you need, but wouldn't the whole row (i.e. every column) be the merge condition? Or are you not concerned about the class? Or is the class what you're trying to update? You could help by showing existing data and what you would expect to happen.

Comment: There's nothing unique to identify rows, it's going to be a very daunting task.

Comment: Show your UPDATE query. Try to write it.

Comment: Since I guess teacher classes can dissappear as well as change classes, it might be better to just clear the data and re-import it.

Comment: What is the uniqueness for each row? Is it the Class, Class+Hour, Class+Hour+Week_Day, Class+Teacher_ID? You could update without a primary key, but you would need to define what is distinct for each row, and that would not change on an Update.

Comment: @apartridge I thought it too, but the program that create the schedules can do it on parts. Ex: When a teacher change his schedule, it can be created a csv file for that teacher only.

Comment: @Sean: Basically, is the class's change that I want to upload, so the "key" will be "teacher_id + day_week + hour".

Comment: But you need to find out what class was dropped. Does your files contain information about that? What if he drops a class and moves to another time slot? It seems more natural that the key is the teacher and the class, which is the only thing likely to stay the same. But then again, there is probably multiple lectures per class, which makes this difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `UNIQUE KEY` on `TEACHER_ID,WEEK_DAY,HOUR` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

```
CREATE UNIQUE KEY classes ON your_table_name (TEACHER_ID,WEEK_DAY,HOUR)`
```

Then you can use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

```
INSERT INTO your_table_name (TEACHER_ID,WEEK_DAY,HOUR,CLASS) VALUES (1234567,2,11:30,MAT001)
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE CLASS=MAT001;
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I needed! But, How can I update the rows for all the teachers differently for each one? `UPDATE CLASS=MAT001` set all the classes into MAT101.

Comment: You would change it to the value of the 4th cell of your csv row. So depending on how you are setting it, it could be something like - `VALUES (cell_1,cell_2,cell_3,cell_4)
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE CLASS=cell_4`